# Finding nested entities with JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Suppose I have Storage entity with Box and Item entities inside. The structure is like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Storage>
    <Box id="1">
        <Item id="1"/>
        <Item color="red" id="2"/>
        <Box id="3">
            <Item id="3" color="red" />
            <Item id="4" color="black" />
        </Box>
        <Box id="6"/>
        <Item id="5"/>
    </Box>
    <Item id="6"/>
</Storage>
```

In order to find items with precise color in precise box I can use this query

```sql
SELECT i FROM Item i where i.box.id =:id and i.color =:color
```

For `box.id = 1` and `color="red"` the output will be an item with id = 2. 
But what if I want to find such item in ALL inner boxes so that item with id = 3 will be included in output? How do I write a query in this case?

Comment: I don't usually associate XML with JPA.. Rather XML with JAXB/XPath.. But there is this.. https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/master/examples/xml-moxy/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/xmlmoxy

Comment: yeah, I already used it. I provided xml just to clarify entity structure

Comment: Also.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_API_for_Java